# How to extract a generic type from a colection in Java

Tags: generics

I am a newbie in Java learning about Generics. I have a question that needs you guys to help.
I have implemented a generic Stack class. In the main method, I declare 2 types of stacks (Integer and String)

```
Stack<Integer> stack1  = new Stack<>();
Stack<String> stack2 = new Stack<>();
```

Is there any way that I can extract the type of these stacks above as String ("Integer" or "String")?

Answer (score 0):

Is is not possible to get that information in runtime due to Type Erasure -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html